# adding saving and deleting function to audio recorder program for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

So I have followed some tutorials online to create an audio recorder app for iphone that allows me to record and playback a sound file.

But I can't find any tutorials that allows me to save the recording into a table view and then choose which file to playback. Can anybody guide me to where I need to modify my code to add a save and delete function?

my code:

(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
// Disable Stop/Play button when application launches
[stopButton setEnabled:NO];
[playButton setEnabled:NO];

// Set the audio file
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                           nil];
NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

// Setup audio session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

// Define the recorder setting
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
recorder.delegate = self;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder prepareToRecord];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the various `NSFileManager` utilities to control the saving and deleting. The `AVAudioRecorder` creates a file on disk when it call `prepareToRecord` so your options after recording are:

1. Delete it (`[[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];`)
2. Don't == save

For the tableview , you could get the audio file names using `NSArray *fileNames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:theDirectoryPath error:&error];`. (btw - I'd create a sub-directory of the docs directory especially for the audio, so you know everything in the dir you're looking at is an audio file. - there's also an NSFileManager method for this. Deleting as above, playing presumably using `AVAudioPlayer` and the paths from the `NSFileManager` calls, in the appropriate delegate/datasource methods